# Perl: Setup multiple package names for variable/functions?

Tags: perl, namespaces, package

First, I'd like to say this isn't a question of design, but a question of compliance.  I'm aware there are issues with the current setup.

In a module, there are packages that are named after the servers, which has many of the same variables/functions that pertain to that server.  It looks like this was set up so that you could do:

- `PRODUCTION_SERVER_NAME::printer()` or
  `TEST_SERVER_NAME::printer()`

Perhaps a better design might have been something like:

- `CENTRAL_PACKAGE_NAME::printer('production')` or `CENTRAL_PACKAGE_NAME::printer('test')`

Anyhow, it seems the server names have changed, so instead of using the actual servernames, I'd like to rename the packages to just `PRODUCTION` or `TEST`, without changing the other code that is still refering to `PRODUCTION_SERVER_NAME`.

Something like:

```
package PRODUCTION, PRODUCTION_SERVER_NAME;  # pseudo code
```

I'm guessing some sort of glob/import might work, but was wondering if there is already something that does something similar.  I also realize it's not good practice to saturate namespaces.

Answer (score 3):

I am not providing any comments on the design or anything that might involve changing client code. Functions in `MyTest.pm` can be accessed using either `MyTest::` or `MyExam::`. However, you can't use `use MyExam` because the physical file is not there. You could do clever `@INC` tricks, but my programs always crash and burn when I try to be clever.

#### MyTest.pm

```
package MyTest;

sub hello { 'Hello' }
sub twoplustwo { 4 }

for my $sub (qw( hello twoplustwo)) {
    no strict 'refs';
    *{"MyExam::$sub"} = *{"MyTest::$sub"};
}

1;
```

#### test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use MyTest;

say MyExam::hello();
say MyExam::twoplustwo();
```

Output:

```
Hello
4
```

Comment: This looks promising - nice to see you again Sinan

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [`aliased`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/aliased)?  It sounds like it could work for you.

Comment: nick, would you using *alias* w/in the module?  The major point is that I don't want to have to notify users that the package/module has changed and I don't want to change all the old code.  If I can't do this unobtrusively, then I'll have to leave it as-is.

Comment: the only change you would need to make would be the use line in your existing code - everything else would remain untouched

Answer (score 0):

Try [`Exporter::Auto`](http://metacpan.org/module/Exporter%3a%3aAuto):

```
package Foo;

use Exporter::Auto;

sub foo {
    print('foo');
}

package Bar;

use Foo;

package main;

Foo::foo();
Bar::foo();
```